# The infimum of the given set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> What is the infimum of $A = \{3^{2x} + 3^{\frac{1}{2x}}  | x > 0\}$?

Without guessing, how do you determine the infimum of that set? Many advises tell us to guessing $x$, but for this problem, it is not sound that easy. Please, help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Arithmetic-Geometric inequality,
\begin{align*}
3^{2x}+3^{1/(2x)}\geq 2(3^{2x}\cdot3^{1/(2x)})^{1/2}=2\cdot 3^{(2x+(2x)^{-1})/2}\geq 2\cdot 3^{((2x)(2x)^{-1})^{1/2}}=2\cdot 3=6,
\end{align*}
and the equality holds if and only if $3^{2x}=3^{1/(2x)}$ and $2x=(2x)^{-1}$. For $x>0$, we can take $x=1/2$ to satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

One term is strictly increasing, the other strictly decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ so the minimum (equal to infimum due to continuoty) is when their exponents are equal, namely $x=\frac{1}{2},$ giving infimum 6.

Comment: I don't see how you can justify the claim that the minimum occurs  "when their exponents are equal" based only on the knowledge that "one term is strictly increasing" and "the other is strictly decreasing".

Comment: You're right, I was hasty. Could have invoked the symmetry mapping $u\rightarrow 1/u$ (with $u=2x,$ between the two functions, which then gives you a minimum when $u=1.$

Comment: I still don't see it. Can you edit your answer to incorporate the needed justifications?